# Telegram bot won't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm writing my first bot in node.js, created an empty project.
I entered (npm init -y) in the console and the file was created package.json
Where I added via the console (npm i telegraf@3.39) and (npm i nodemon)
used Node.js v16.10.0

```
{
  "name": "second_project_bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "telegraf": "3.39"
  }
}
```

Then I created a js file and wrote a simple code there

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf('my token')

bot.command('start', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    
})
bot.launch()
```

I'm trying to run it through a command in the console (npm start) and I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjptk.png)

I tried to install another version Node.js (20.11.0) I thought this was the problem but installing the new version did not help

Comment: How did you start the bot?

Comment: I've followed your steps on node 21.1 and the bot is working just fine.

Comment: In the VS Code terminal I wrote the command npm start.

Comment: How did you name the file as shown in the second code block?

Comment: I named the file index.js

Comment: I've voted to close this as not reproducible as using your exact code + command works just fine. Try updating node to 21+

Answer (score 0):

The index.js file should be located in the same directory as the package.json file. I suspect your index.js is in the src folder :)

Comment: The most interesting thing is that my index.js file is located in the same directory as package.js